# How to get the count of distinct values for a certain label in prometheus?

Tags: prometheus

We are monitoring kafka consumers with prometheus and grafana by drawing a consuming rate curve per topic and partition. We noticed that a consumer for some partition may stop working because of some error. It would be convenient to add an alert if there is some function that counts the number of distinct partitions (as a label value) that's being consumed.

Update:

We have a time series like this:

```
consume_rate_count{topic="my-kafka-topic",partition="0"} 320 1495164869031
consume_rate_count{topic="my-kafka-topic",partition="1"} 316 1495164869031
consume_rate_count{topic="my-kafka-topic",partition="2"} 331 1495164869031
consume_rate_count{topic="my-kafka-topic",partition="3"} 322 1495164869031
```

And we're looking for way to get the count of distinct partitions with a positive consume rate. So if we get the following data, an alert will be trigger, because we have 4 partitions in total, but only 3 of them is being consumed.

```
consume_rate_count{topic="my-kafka-topic",partition="0"} 320 1495164869031
consume_rate_count{topic="my-kafka-topic",partition="1"} 316 1495164869031
consume_rate_count{topic="my-kafka-topic",partition="2"} 0   1495164869031
consume_rate_count{topic="my-kafka-topic",partition="3"} 322 1495164869031
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the time series in question and what pattern you're looking for?

Comment: @brian-brazil I updated the question with some data example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`consume_rate_count == 0` will do it.

Answer (score 0):

The following query returns the number of per-topic partitions with non-zero consume rate:

```
count(consume_rate_count > 0) without (partition)
```

The query uses `>` operator and [count()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#count) [aggregate function](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#aggregate-functions) for counting the number of non-zero time series and grouping them by all the labels except `partition`. See [these docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#comparison-binary-operators) about `>` operator.

The following query returns the number of per-topic partitions with zero consume rate:

```
count(consume_rate_count == 0) without (partition)
```

The following query returns non-empty result (e.g. an alert) for topics with at least a single partition with zero consume rate if this topic contains at least a single partition with non-zero consume rate:

```
count(consume_rate_count == 0) without (partition) > 0
  and
count(consume_rate_count > 0) without (partition) > 0
```

This query uses `and` operator, which returns time series on the left side only if there are time series with the same set of labels on the right side - see [these docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#logical-set-binary-operators) for details about this operator.